# python Django - Convert SQL Query to ORM Query

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

I want sql query to orm

```
SELECT id, title,
(SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) FROM web_history A WHERE A.car_id = B.id AND type = 3)
FROM web_car B;


histories = History.objects.filter(car=OuterRef('pk'), type=3)
cars = Car.objects.annotate(count=Subquery(histories.annotate(a=Sum('amount'))))
```

This can not be done by setting the output_field ... I can not solve it even if I apply variously from FloatField to Char through Concat.
I leave a comment on whether I can get advice.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be overcomplicating things. You just need a query on Car which annotates the related Histories where type=3.

```
Car.objects.filter(history__type=3).annotate(count=Sum('history__amount'))
```

Comment: Hm.. How do you access the History table? 'Type' and 'Amount' are the columns of History

Comment: You use the double-underscore syntax, see my edit - I was already doing so for type, needed to add it for history as well.